# Extract 2 different and non-consecutive lines from text without creating temporary text files

Tags: bash, awk

I'm a musician and do a little programming on the side, so my abilities are limited, please forgive me.

Sometimes I need the LUFS level of multiple audio files and the quickest way (for me...) was to use ffmpeg to calculate that, because it does it offline in a few seconds for a file, instead of having to play it all the way through in the DAW for a readout.

The is the script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/zsh

TempDirectory="~/Desktop/TEMP"

TempRAW="$TempDirectory/ffmpeg_LUFS_output_RAW.txt"
OutputCSV="$TempDirectory/ffmpeg_LUFS_output.csv"

for CurrentFile in "$@" 
do

    echo "File: "$(/usr/bin/basename "$CurrentFile") >>"$TempRAW"

    /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -i "$CurrentFile" -hide_banner -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2>>"$TempRAW"

done

# The next part extracts the info from the raw ffmpeg output file 
# The output from ffmpeg is 55 lines
# Line 1:  File: LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
# ... snip ...
# Line 47: Integrated loudness:
# Line 48:   I:         -32.2 LUFS
# Line 49:   Threshold: -42.6 LUFS
#
# The lines that interest me are Line 1 + 48:


while IFS= read -r line
do

    if [[ "$line" =~ ^"File: " ]]; then
    printf "$line," | sed 's/File: //' >>"$OutputCSV"
    fi

    if [[ "$line" =~ ^"    I:" ]]; then
    echo "$line" | sed 's/    I:         //'>>"$OutputCSV"
    fi

done < "$TempRAW"
```

It works, my problem is solved how my abilities allowed me to solve it.

But I would have preferred to not have to write temporary files.

While I was writing this, I searched at least 4 hours for solutions. Most of them explained to do it with awk working on the ffmpeg output stored in a variable. But awk would always create doubled results for the first entry ( I probably did something wrong...).

How would I write this without temporary files?

Here is more sample lines of the output:

```
File: LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '/Volumes/Project HDD/Leopard Skin/Themes/Bounces/LSK Adore v18 STEMS 78bpm/LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Logic Pro X
    originator_reference: aaO3N!Fzk7Rk
    date            : 2021-05-24
    creation_time   : 18:48:28
    time_reference  : 276258449
...
SNIP
...
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
size=N/A time=00:01:49.21 bitrate=N/A speed= 766x    
video:0kB audio:20481kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 0x153f0af90] Summary:

  Integrated loudness:
    I:         -32.2 LUFS
    Threshold: -42.6 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:         4.9 LU
    Threshold: -52.7 LUFS
    LRA low:   -34.5 LUFS
    LRA high:  -29.6 LUFS
```

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of data generated by the `ffmpeg` command (5-10 lines, including lines that are to be ignored; cut really long lines down to something small enough to represent the format), the `awk` code you've attempted, the (wrong) output generated by your `awk` code, and the (correct) expected output ... making sure both sets of output correspond with the provided sample input

Comment: Part of the output is already in the comments within the code, but I will add more lines if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reconstruct the awk command that I had and the way it followed the ffmpeg anymore. :-(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. It's not clear if the block of text under `Here is more sample lines of the output:` is the input you want a tool to work on or the output you want a tool to produce but either way the other thing (sample input or expected output) is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with a single loop. One approach would be:

```
for CurrentFile in "$@"; do
    printf '%s,' "${CurrentFile##*/}"
    ffmpeg -i "$CurrentFile" -hide_banner -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2> >(sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*I:[[:blank:]]*//p')
done > "$OutputCSV"
```

Comment: OMG: This is also a wonderful answer... in this case I would have never known that the > > works... or is allowed even...

Comment: @tanzpartner `>(...)` is process substitution. You may want to read the [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output into `sed`, and let it filter the first line (`1p`), and the line below the one containing "Integrated loudness" (`/Integrated loudness/{n;p}`):

```bash
ffmpeg -i "$CurrentFile" … 2>&1 | sed -n '1p;/Integrated loudness/{n;p}'
```

```
File: LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
    I:         -32.2 LUFS
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- we only want the data that comes after the strings `^File:<white space>` and `<white_space>I:<white_space>`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '{ if (match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/)) print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }'
```

Where:

- we look for a match of one of two patterns:
- `^File:[[:space:]]*` or
- `^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*`
- if `match(...)` returns a non-zero value then ...
- `substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)` extracts that portion of the line that comes after the match (`RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set by a successful `match(...)`)

OP can then feed the `ffmpeg` output to this command in one of two methods:

```
ffmpeg ... | awk '{ .... }'

# or

awk '{ .... }' < <(ffmpeg ...)
```

Using a local file to simulate OP's `ffmpeg` output:

```
$ cat ffmpeg.out
File: LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from '/Volumes/Project HDD/Leopard Skin/Themes/Bounces/LSK Adore v18 STEMS 78bpm/LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Logic Pro X
    originator_reference: aaO3N!Fzk7Rk
    date            : 2021-05-24
    creation_time   : 18:48:28
    time_reference  : 276258449
...
SNIP
...
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
size=N/A time=00:01:49.21 bitrate=N/A speed= 766x
video:0kB audio:20481kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_ebur128_0 @ 0x153f0af90] Summary:

  Integrated loudness:
    I:         -32.2 LUFS
    Threshold: -42.6 LUFS

  Loudness range:
    LRA:         4.9 LU
    Threshold: -52.7 LUFS
    LRA low:   -34.5 LUFS
    LRA high:  -29.6 LUFS
```

Running this through the `awk` code:

```
$ cat ffmpeg.out | awk '{ if (match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/)) print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }'
LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
-32.2 LUFS
```

---

Alternatively we can place the `awk` script in a file:

```
$ cat ffmpeg.awk
{ if (match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/)) print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }
```

And the invocation becomes:

```
$ cat ffmpeg.out | awk -f ffmpeg.awk
LSK Adore v18 [Dreamy] MIX ALL Stereo.wav
-32.2 LUFS
```

---

Another variation where we move the `match()` test outside the action block:

```
awk 'match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }'

# or

$ cat ffmpeg.awk
match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't reconstruct why I didn't get awk to work. But your solution does what I wanted. I still don't understand how awk really works... its power is a bit over my head. But at least I can copy paste... :-/

Comment: But what I learned here was the "if" construction within {} brackets - I also would have never known that...

Comment: in this case we could also move the test outside the action block, eg: `awk 'match($0,/^File:[[:space:]]*|^.[[:space:]]*I:[[:space:]]*/) { print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }'`; I'll update the answer with this additional variation

Answer (score 0):

The concept you really need is simply unix pipes (`|`):

```
for CurrentFile in "$@" 
do
        
    echo $(/usr/bin/basename "$CurrentFile") >>"$OutputCSV"
        
    /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -i "$CurrentFile" -hide_banner -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - |&
    
    while IFS= read -r line
    do

        if [[ "$line" =~ ^"    I:" ]]; then
        echo "$line" | sed 's/    I:         //'>>"$OutputCSV"
        fi
    
    done 
        
done
```

Comment: I can have multiple lines after the pipe | ?

Comment: The pipe provides stdin to the while command, just as the < did in your original try.

Answer (score 0):

@tanzpartner :

if you're simply looking to extract the 1st pass output of `loudnorm` filter in `ffmpeg` to feed it as 2nd pass input, here's the combo of shell functions + some `awk` to automate it :

```
ldn () {
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo " "
        echo " usage   : ldn FN    StrmIdxAbs -ss -to"
        echo " default : ldn (n/a) a:0        0   999"
        echo " "
        echo " example : ldn \"G7.vob\" 4 25.5 60"
        echo " "
        return 1
    fi
    ch2 "${@}" | ldn_util_summary
    return
}

ch2 () {
    [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]] && echo && echo " needs fileName..." && echo && return 1
    inF="$( nice echo "${1}" | unC3)" 

    # unC3 a python script to normalize to Unicode NFC given 
    # Apple's annoying practice of always showing you NFD form at ([ ls ]),
    # regardless of the actual codepoints in the file names.  
    # Trim out that part if aren't dealing with multibyte chars

    [[ "$#" -ge 2 ]] && {
        stridx="${2}" 
    } || {
        stridx='a:0' 
    }
    [[ "$#" -ge 3 ]] && {
        tstart="${3}" 
        tfnish="${4}" 
    } || {
        tstart='0' 
        tfnish="$( nice ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries fomat=duration 

                                -of default=nk=1:nw=1 
                                 
                                -i "${inF}" )" 
    }
     
    # I only spaced it out for readability - 
    # there aren't any new lines within the same ffmpeg command 

    ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -ss "${tstart}" -to "${tfnish}" 

           -i "${inF}" -f nut -map_metadata -1 -vn -dn -sn 

           -map 0:"${stridx}" -c:a pcm_f64le -ac 2 -ar 48000
            
           -muxpreload 0 -copyts -output_ts_offset 0 -hide_banner -v 0 -
}
```

---

```
ldn_util_summary () {
    ldn_util_summary_1 | ldn_util_summary_2
}

ldn_util_summary_1 () {

         ff -hide_banner -i "pipe:0" 
            -vn 
               -sn 
                  -dn 
            -af 'loudnorm=-11:7:-2:dual_mono=true:print_format=json' 
            -map_metadata -1 
            
            -f null /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

> here, I'm using `awk` to directly extract the values from `JSON` output without any proper `JSON` parsing module/utility

```
ldn_util_summary_2 () {

    mawk 'BEGIN { FS = "\42"
                  OFS = "\72"

        } NF == 5 && $3 ~ /[ \t][:][ \t]/ ) {

            varL[$2] = +$4

        } END {

            print "loudnorm" "=" "-11", "7", "-2",
                     \
             ( (varL["input_i"]       >  0) ||
               (varL["input_thresh"]  >  0) ||
               (varL["input_tp"]      > 99) ||
               (varL["input_lra"]     <  0) ||
               (varL["target_offset"] > 99)    ) ? \
                    \
                "dual_mono" "=" "true" : \
                                 \
                    varL["input_i"],
                    varL["input_lra"],
                    varL["input_tp"],
                    varL["input_thresh"],
                    varL["target_offset"],
                    \
                "true", "true", "summary" }'
}
```

So at the actual `ffmpeg` run, this enables me to do

> **`ffmpeg -i "$inputFile" … -af "$( ldn -i "$inputFile" )..." …`**

And defaulting to the `1st—pass` parameters if extreme values were reported that likely causes painful squeaking

There are more fancy options for `ldn` for customized `starting` point, `ending` point, and exactly which `audio stream` to be normalized if multiple exists

---

I needed `ch2()` to go first because the normalized parameters could be skewed if it normalized **5.1** or **7.1** inputs in strange manners, so I use a very high bit rate `PCM` intermediary format to pre-normalize all inputs to stereo-only channels before the `loudnorm` filter part.

*Skip that part at your discretion*